# i want to add default value in select box using turbo-stream in rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, turbo

I am using ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.3.1, I am updating the select box value using turbo stream, it's updating the value of the select box but not adding default value on it.

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
  root "dropdown#country"
  get "/state", to: "dropdown#state"
  get "/city", to: "dropdown#city"
```

form for dynamic select dropdown
**app/views/dropdown/country.html.erb**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
    <h1>Dynamic Drop Down Select Using Stimulus
    </h1>
    <div class="container mt-4" data-controller="dropdown--selectdropdown" data-dropdown--selectdropdown-url-value="/state" >
        <%= form_with url: "/" do |form| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= form.label :country %>
                        <%= form.select :country, CS.countries.invert, {include_blank: "Select"}, class: "form-select", data: { action: "change->dropdown--selectdropdown#country", dropdown__selectdropdown_target: "country" } %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group" data-cityurl="/city" data-dropdown--selectdropdown-target="city">
                        <%= form.label :state %>
                        <%= form.select :state, options_for_select([]),{include_blank: "Select"},class: "form-select",data: { action: "change->dropdown--selectdropdown#city" } %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= form.label :city %>
                        <%= form.select :city, options_for_select([]),{include_blank: "Select"},class: "form-select" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

app/controllers/dropdown_controller.rb

```
class DropdownController < ApplicationController
  def country
  end

  def state
   if params[:country] == ""
    @states = ["Select"]
   else
    @states = CS.states(params[:country]).invert
    
   end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
    end
  end

  def city
    @cities = CS.cities(params[:state],params[:country])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
    end
  end

end
```

**app/javascipt/controller/selectdropdown_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { get } from "@rails/request.js"

// Connects to data-controller="dropdown--selectdropdown"
export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ["country","city"]

  static values = {
    url: String
  }

  connect() {
    // console.log();
  }

  country(event){
    this.countryRequest(event)
  }

  countryRequest(event){
    let params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append("country",event.target.value)
    get(`${this.urlValue}?${params}`,{
      responseKind: "turbo-stream"
    })
  }

  city(event){
    this.cityRequest(event)
  }

  cityRequest(event){
    get(`${this.cityTarget.dataset.cityurl}`,{
      query:{
        state: event.target.value,
        country: this.countryTarget.value
      },
      responseKind: "turbo-stream"
    })
  }

}
```

**app/views/dropdown/city.turbo_stream.erb**

```
<%= turbo_stream.update "city" do %>
    <%= options_for_select @cities %> 
<% end %>
```

app/views/dropdown/state.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.update "state" do %>
    <%= options_for_select @states, prompt: "Select" %>
<% end %>
```

need to add one default value in the state and city dropdown select box, when updating the select box value using turbo stream.

thank!

Comment: could anyone please help me for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to have a default value assigned when you render the form you would assign it like:

```
default_value_here = "USA" or what ever the CS select_field value is

<%= form.select :state, options_for_select([], default_value_here),{include_blank: "Select"},class: "form-select",data: { action: "change->dropdown--selectdropdown#city" } %>
```

Turbo field should be no different its still using the `options_for_select` helper

```
<%= options_for_select(@cities, default_value_here) %>
```

If you want the assigned attribute to show when editing, replace `default_value_here` with `form.object.city` / `form.object.state` for the form. In the turbo I'm not %100 but I believe the same idea would work so `object.city`

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

> options_for_select(container, selected = nil)

```
container = whatever value you are trying to assign
selected = the default value to be assigned
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I was trying to solve the same issue so it might help a fellow weary travelling with the same issue.

One solution is to add a 'Select' option to the @states array

```
@states = CS.states(params[:country]).invert
@states.unshift(['Select', ''])
```

Then in your turbo stream

```
<%= turbo_stream.update "state" do %>
    <%= options_for_select @states, "" %>
<% end %>
```

And just make sure you have validations in place to check that the user cannot submit the form without selecting a state.